# How to only check that checkbox which is entered in textbox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to only check that checkbox which is entered in textbox ?

If i have 4 checkboxes eith text checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3 and checkbox4 and 1 textbox

if i type in textbox 1,2 then only checkbox1 and checkbox2 would be checked again directly after doing that i type 3,4 in textbox then only 3,4 will be checked and 1,2 will be uncheked..

remember i wanna do this coding for unlimited no. of checkboxes .. so dnt provide coding for 4 checkboxes only ..... provide me the coding for that for unlimited checkboxes...

Comment: Pictures or it didn't happen!

Comment: -1 for a confusing question, -1 for asking for a complete solution, -1 for not showing any attempt at solving it yourself -- too bad I only have one downvote.  Seriously, try a little harder.

Comment: uhm, that's funny http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173949/i-have-4-checkboxes-and-1-textbox-in-webform-if-i-type-in-textbox-1-2-then-checkb . Unluckyly I already voted to close as "not a real question"

Comment: It's funny that an answer was already given for the previous question.

Comment: Don't you wanna choose the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through all your checkboxes and uncheck them before you check the new ones.

Comment: Can u please provide me the coding in vb.net ?

Comment: Aren't you trying to start a company that provides web development services? I would expect such a company to be able to that itself.

Comment: Can u please provide us ur attemptz?

Answer (score 0):

try using a naming convention for TextBoxes and CheckBoxes. so if you use one TextChanged event handler for all of them, you can use `Sender` parameter to identify which text box is changing. then uncheck previous check box and check new one:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public oldCheckBox As CheckBox

    Private Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.TextChanged, TextBox3.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged, TextBox1.TextChanged
        Dim x As TextBox = sender
        Dim i As Integer = x.Text.Substring(7) // 7 = length of "TextBox" 
        Dim relatedCheckBox As CheckBox = Me.Controls("CheckBox" + i.ToString())
        relatedCheckBox.Checked = True

        If (oldCheckBox IsNot Nothing) And (oldCheckBox IsNot relatedCheckBox) Then
            oldCheckBox.Checked = False
        End If

        oldCheckBox = relatedCheckBox
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I dont know anything .. iwant a coding 4 that ...

Comment: try on topcoder.com, they surely have a coding 4 that.

Comment: Can i use this coding in asp.net (vb)